# Placeholder Text in InfoPath/SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath, form, browser-enabled-form

I have an InfoPath form in which I'd like to add PlaceHolder text to a few textbox fields.  I believe it's currently set to open in the browser because the placeholders won't display when users open a new form from the SP list.  Is there a way to change how users open the form so that they can view the placeholder text?  I'd like to avoid having to create a completely new InfoPath form from scratch because of this.

Thank you so much!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In InfoPath browser-enabled form, for placeholder text, you can use the "**Screen tips**", the as usual placeholder text will not work in the Infopath browser-enabled form.

**OR**

You can add some static text to a section and having a format rule on the section that hides it if the text field is not blank.

You can also have a button that displays the text and when you click the button, reverts to a textbox (hides button and shows textbox on click), and if the textbox is empty it reverts (hide textbox and show button0.

Pretty easy to do these things using a "toggle" field to store the hide-show value and conditional formatting rules.

Reference:

[Alternative to Placeholder text?](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/27613.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much.  The screen tips will work perfectly.